# how to convert functional interface to use lambda function

Tags: java, lambda, interface

In learnign how to use the functional interfaces and lambda function, i was reading a tutorial and in the attempt of creating an example as shown below I encountered an error which is displayed below.
please let me know how to use lambda function correctly in the below example

**error**:

```
left-handside of the assignment must be a variable
```

**interface**

```
public interface MyInterface1 {
    
default public void defaultMethod1(String text, int i){
    System.out.println("defaultMethod1: " + text + " " + i + "times");
}

default public void defaultMethod2(String text, int i){
    System.out.println("defaultMethod2: " + text + " " + i + "times");
}


static void printItToSystemOut(String text){
    System.out.println(text);
}

int method1(String s, int i);
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    MyInterface1 myInterface = ("yxc", 3)-> {//<----ERROR
        
        return 3;
    };
}

}
```

Comment: did you mean `(i, j) ->` the left hand of the lambda can't hold values

Comment: @YCF_L would mind provide the consummation or the complementary part of the hint/answer you provided

Comment: What did you mean by *consummation*, honestly, I don't know what you are trying to achieve by your code!

Comment: The part between `=` and `->` is a parameter list, with just the *names* of the parameters, e.g. `MyInterface1 myInterface = (s, i) -> { return 3; };`. You provide the *values* later on when you *call* the method, e.g. `int x = myInterface.method1("yxc", 3);`.

Comment: I managed to solve it as well with this example: MyInterface1 myInterface = (str, i)-> {
   
   return "str :: " + (i*10);
  };
  
  String s = myInterface.method1("md", 3);
  System.out.print(s);